# How do I use Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax with libman (Library manager) asp.net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use unobtrusive ajax to update my partial views. Unfortunately I ran in to a problem when I was about to install the package, since Bower is not working (?) or recommended anymore according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.1. Instead they recommend us to use Libman.

I followed the steps from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/unobtrusive-ajax-and-jquery-for-partial-updates-in-asp-net-mvc/.

So I have installed the nuget Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax-package, but how do I reference the ajax-package with libman?

I looked at this [How to reference Microsoft.JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax within my ASP.NET Core MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848181/how-to-reference-microsoft-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-within-my-asp-net-core-mvc-pr) answer but it only shows how to use Bower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use npm. Add pakage.json file in the root of your web project

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "your-system",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "exclude": [
  ]
}
```

Now everything related to the library will be automatically downloaded in `node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive`.

Be aware the node_module folder is not part of the project so you need to click `Show All Files` to see all folders.

[image]

After that if you want to always have latest version of the library instead of copying the file to your js folder you could use bundle config. Run this:

```
Install-Package BuildBundlerMinifier -Version 2.8.391
```

After that create json file - `bundleconfig.json` in the root of your web project

```
[ 
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/myjs.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
    ]
  }

]
```

This will create on every build `myjs.min.js` file in your js folder in `wwwroot`

Answer (score 12):

I struggled with LibMan at first too.  I found [this guide that points out there's a GUI portion of LibMan](https://www.maherjendoubi.io/using-cdnjs-with-libman-for-aspnetcore/).  Using the UI portion of LibMan under the "project right click menu -> Add -> Client-Side Library" helped me figure out better ways to define which files I want and change the provider easier.

I ended up having most of my files come from cdnjs, but I set up jquery-ajax-unobtrusive to come from unpkg like so:

```
{
    "provider": "unpkg",
    "library": "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.6",
    "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/"
}
```

Comment: I tried to add through the gui... didn't work. Pasting that block into libman.json - did. Ain't that a...

Answer (score 10):

The answer by @mybirthname  is great . Another way to do that is to use libman cli . We can use the following command to install the libman :

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli
```

And now you can install jquery , jquery-validation-unobtrusive and so on as you like :

to init a `libman.json` :

```
libman init
```

to install a dependency of `jquery-validation-unobtrusive`:

```
> libman install jquery-validation-unobtrusive
Destination [lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive]:
lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js written to disk
lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js written to disk
Installed library "jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.10" to "lib\jquery-validation-unobtrusive"
```

to install a depenency of `jquery`:

```
> libman install jquery
Destination [lib\jquery]:
lib/jquery/core.js written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.js written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.min.js written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.min.map written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.slim.js written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js written to disk
lib/jquery/jquery.slim.min.map written to disk
Installed library "jquery@3.3.1" to "lib\jquery"
```

**[Edit]**

To install `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` on npm,  since it's not yet on cdnjs, we can use unpkg provider :

> unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm

```
libman install -p unpkg jquery-ajax-unobtrusive
```

Comment: Hi @itminus, I think you've missed the point of the question. The OP wanted to know how to include jquery.ajax.unobtrusive in his project as currently this is not available from cdnjs. I too want this and it looks like many other do too.

Comment: @lan GM Hi,  I've updated my answer to show a way to install `jquery-ajax-unobtrusive` using libman cli .

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. I am away from the project until next week but looking forward to giving it a go. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has written a help document on Managing Client-Side Library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It has steps to use the 'Add Client-Side Library dialog' in Visual Studio. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project folder in which the files should be added. Choose Add > Client-Side Library. The Add Client-Side Library dialog appears.